# Laravel Nova - Confirmation modal for update resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Is there a way to display a confirmation modal like when deleting resource for update case? See the screenshot below.
[image]

I didn't find any solution yet. I saw few more similar questions but no one answered. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could debug the code and check where resides file shown in the image. Then you can reproduce similar for other request. I am not using Nova, just proposing where I'd go first.